# How to find how many numbers do not contain the digit n in the range from a to b?

Tags: algorithms, puzzle

> How to find how many numbers do not contain the digit $5$ in the range from $[a,b]$, where $a$  and b are integers and $b ≥ a$

Subject to condition, 5 can be  various positions of the number.like $345$ includes $5$ and $1576$ includes $5$ in different positions.

---

```
Examples:

[1,9] -> {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9} -> Result 8
[4,17] -> {4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,16,17} -> Result 12
[98, 990] -> Result 639
```

I am still moving from what I know, and this is the search for such numbers in the ranges 1 - 10, 1 - 100, 1 - 1000.

*a = 1; b = 1000; с - number of digits in 1000, m - number of digits without 5*
$$n = m^c also (9^3 = 729)$$

*All calculations are for integer values.*

---

Yes, indeed, this is a task related to programming, but the logic and calculation are mathematical.[Source](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5813d19765d81c592200001a)

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: What kind of answer are you after? A formula or a program or something else?

Comment: Suppose $a$ and $b$ are integers and $b\geq a$. $n=b+1-a$, If $a\leq 5$ and $b\geq 5$ then $m=n-1$ else $m=n$. $m$ is result.

Comment: @Arthur Formula

Comment: When you edit to include your efforts, also indicate the source of the problem.  It sounds more like a programming challenge than a math problem.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu: I think it is clear that the OP is asking about integers that don't contain a $5$ anywhere in their decimal representation.

Comment: I think it's going to be easier to find how may contain at least one $5$.

Comment: @Astrodynamic Yes,  the logic and calculation are mathematical. And this is a math forum. And as such, question are expected to be written in math notation, not in programming notation. Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @jjagmath Ok I understood. At the beginning I was confused by your mathematical notation, I am writing for the first time on this forum. All remarks for the future will be taken into account.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228366/how-to-count-each-numeral-of-occurrences-of-digits/1229292#1229292  you can check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem becomes trivial if you :

- Insist on zero filling on the left.  This is permitted, because the digit whose occurrences are being interrogated is not $0$.  So, for example, interpreting $(10)$ as $(0010)$ does not alter whether a number contains at least one occurrence of the digit $5$.
- Crouch the problem in a **symmetric** range.  For instance, one example of a symmetric range would be the numbers $0000$ thru $9999$.  Here, when examining each of the numbers from $0$ through $9999$, inclusive, it is clear that within each of the $4$ digit places, from right to left (i.e. the $10^0$ place, the $10^1$ place, the $10^2$ place, and the $10^3$ place) you see the $0$ through $9$ pattern over and over and over.
- **Convert** the problem from a counting (i.e. Combinatorics) problem into a Probability (i.e. frequency) problem.

For example, suppose that you wanted to know how many of the numbers in the range $0000$ through $9999$ do not contain at least one occurrence of the digit $5$.

Because of the symmetry of the range, you can regard the occurrence of the digit $5$ as actually encapsulating $4$ **independent** events: namely, the occurrence of the digit $5$ in position $~10^k ~: ~k \in \{0,1,2,3\}.$

Here, the probability that a number chosen at random will not have the digit $5$ in position $k$ is $~\displaystyle \frac{9}{10}.$

Therefore, the count of the numbers in the range $0000$ through $9999$ inclusive that do not contain at least one occurrence of the digit $5$ must be

$$10^4 \times \left[\frac{9}{10}\right]^4 = 9^4.$$

Comment: I think correctly, for 1 to 4444 ;$4 \times 5 \times 5 \times5$; and for 5555 $4 \times 5 \times 5 \times5$; just because we don't include the number 5.

Comment: @Astrodynamic I don't understand your comment.  Could you please elaborate on what you are trying to say.  Also, if your comment involves Math, please express the Math with [Mathjax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  For example, $5 \times 8^3$ can be expressed as `$5 \times 8^3$`.

Comment: @Astrodynamic Re my response, you must be very careful when considering whether the range is **symmetric**.  For example, if instead of the range $0000$ through $9999$ you examined the range $0000$ through $7999$, you would have to give special consideration to the fact that the probability that the digit in the $10^3$ place is **not** $5$ is $~\displaystyle \frac{7}{8}~$ rather than $~\displaystyle \frac{9}{10}$.

Comment: @Astrodynamic As another pitfall, consider the numbers in the range $50$ through $64$.  Within this range, consider the $2$ events of an occurrence of the digit $5$ in the $10^0$ place, and the occurrence of the digit $5$ in the $10^1$ place.  In the range $50$ through $64$, these $2$ events are **not independent**.  For example, if the $10^1$ place is not equal to $5$, in that range, then it is **impossible** for the $10^0$ digit to be a $5$.